# Adding rowspan via XSL

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<Loci>
    <Locus>
        <Id>MTBC1726</Id>
        <Alleles>
            <Allele>
                <Name>1.0</Name>
                <Description>No annotation provided</Description>
            </Allele>
            <Allele>
                <Name>2.0</Name>
                <Description>No annotation provided</Description>
            </Allele>
        </Alleles>
    </Locus>
    <Locus>
        <Id>MTBC3142</Id>
        <Alleles>
            <Allele>
                <Name>1.0</Name>
                <Description>No annotation provided</Description>
            </Allele>
        </Alleles>
    </Locus>
</Loci>
```

And I want to create the following result:

[image]

which, in HTML, would look like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Locus</th>
    <th>Allele</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">MTBC1726</td>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td >No annotation provided</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.0</td>
    <td >No annotation provided</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >MTBC3142</td>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td >No annotation provided</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have created the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Locus</th>
        <th>Allele</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Loci/Locus">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Id"/></td>
        <xsl:for-each select="Alleles/Allele">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but that produces a table like this:

[image]

So, my question is: how do I add the `rowspan` attribute with a count based on the number of `<Allele>` nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Locus</th>
    <th>Allele</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Loci/Locus">
    <xsl:for-each select="Alleles/Allele">
      <tr>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <td rowspan="{last()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Locus[1]/Id"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

The idea here is that within the inner `for-each` you can use `position()` to see whether you're on the first `Allele` for this `Locus`, and `last()` to give the number of `Allele` elements that the current `Locus` contains.  The `ancestor::Locus[1]` is because we need to extract the `Locus` Id at a point where the current context is its first `Allele`.

If you want to avoid adding `rowspan="1"` for single-allele loci, you'll have to use a conditional `xsl:attribute` instead of an attribute value template:

```
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <td>
            <xsl:if test="last() &gt; 1">
              <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                <xsl:value-of select="last()" />
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Locus[1]/Id"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the XSL count() function to define a variable, and then output that variable as your attribute value:

```
<xsl:variable name="recordCount" select="count(Alleles/Allele)"/>
<td rowspan="{$recordCount}"><xsl:value-of select="Id"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of `Allele` and use that value to create your rowspan. I also put in a check so that it didn't add a `rowspan=1` for cases when there was only the one `Allele`

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Locus</th>
        <th>Allele</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Loci/Locus">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:if test="count(Alleles/Allele) &gt; 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(Alleles/Allele)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
        </td>
        <xsl:for-each select="Alleles/Allele">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```